# How to change the value on a input in someone else page?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="xCoord">
    <label for="xCoordInput">X:</label>
    <input value="" name="x" id="xCoordInput" class="text coordinates x ">
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to change this value (`xCoordInput`) on someone else website? This is a game and I don't know how I would change their website from my own website.

Comment: You can't change someone else's website without access to their server.

Comment: That is called hacking...

Comment: OK thanks I didn't realize it @Sanpopo

Comment: @Sanpopo One more question are Automatically Fill Web Forms programs illegal. Or could that be used to enter information?

Comment: @ruthless no, those are not illegal

Comment: No, you can build extensions for popular browsers, if you know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to autofill forms with a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet%E2%80%8E). I use them at work to fill out tedious forms when I am testing webpages. To build one create a bookmark and edit the url value of the bookmark to hold a javascript function object like this one.

```
javascript:(function(){ 
    var xCoord = document.getElementsByClassName("xCoord")[0];
    xCoord.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="whatever";  
})();
```

Nothing about doing this in principle is wrong or illegal unless you are using it to cheat or break the law.